# Continuity of a function such that $\lambda f(x) = f(\lambda x) $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $\lambda f(x) = f(\lambda x) \mbox{   }\forall \lambda, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

I know one shall prove that $f$ is continuous in all its domain. I tried to use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition and prove that $\lambda f(x)$ is continuous, so for the case $\lambda=1$, $f$ is continuous. But I got stuck.

Comment: A fun question working on it !!..... main idea I think I will use is to extend continuity but only if I am done proving at a point. Something that I especially like about it is it is very standard.

Comment: A good start could be to study for every $x$ and every $\epsilon$; $f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)=\frac{\epsilon}{x}f(x)$ and its limits when $\epsilon$ approach $0$.

Comment: You get $f(\lambda) = \lambda f(1)$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is a linear function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

for a given $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{|f(1)|+1}$ such that $|x-a|<\delta $ implies $|f(x) -f(a)|=|f(1\cdot x) -f(1 \cdot a)| = |f(1)\cdot x -f(1) \cdot a| = |f(1)| \cdot|x -a| \leq |f(1)|\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{|f(1)|+1} < \epsilon$.

Hence, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

your function has the form
$$
 f(y)=yf(1)
$$

(proof: use $x=1, \lambda=y$).

hence it is linear and continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=1$ gives you
$$f(\lambda)=\lambda f(1)$$for all $\lambda$, so $f$ is Lipschitz, hence (uniformly) continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=1$, then $f(\lambda)=f(\lambda*1)=\lambda*f(1)$. Hence, with $a:=f(1)$ we have:

$f(x)=ax$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we can write $f(x) = f(x\times 1) = x\times f(1)$, therefore for $\alpha = f(1)\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
f(x) = \alpha x \quad x\in \mathbb{R},
$$
so that if $x_n\to x$
$$
\lim_n f(x_n) = \lim_n \alpha x_n = \alpha x = f(x)
$$